# parsing XML file using PHP (cs-s75: David Malan's)

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am making a PHP project for a Pizza Shop [This is project-0 in David Malan's course CS-S75 Building Dynamic Websites]. And the Code that I have to write must be eXtensible. That is, if the pizza shop's owner wants to add a new category, he should be able to do that pretty easily and my PHP code must accommodate those changes in the XML file without writing any new code.
For my code to be extensible though, I need some methods for filtering the XML data.
For instance inside the root node `<menu>`, I have child nodes **item** that have attributes like

```
    <item name="Pizzas">
        <category name="Onions">
        </category>
    </item>

    <item name="Salads">
        <category name = "Garden">
        </category>
    </item>
```

and there are ten item tags in total.
What I want to do is this: if the user wants to purchase the salads, I would want to filter the XML DOM tree the following way:

```
// $_POST['selected'] has a value of 'Salads' stored in it
$selected = $_POST['selected'] 
$dom = simple_xml_loadfile("menu.xml")
foreach ($dom -> xpath("menu/item[@name = $selected ]" as $item))
{
   echo $item -> category['name'].'<br />';
}
```

And it should print **Garden** and any other item that is subsequently added to the Salads category.The problem occurs with the `menu/item[@name = $selected ]` because this is probably not a proper method for comparing the attribute (Note that attribute comparison like this in XML requires single equal sign and not double equal).And obviously `menu/item[@name = $_POST['selected']]` doesn't work either.
What works is `@name = "Salads"` and of course this kills the whole purpose of the extensiblity of XML and dynamism of PHP. 
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get all `category` nodes that belong to a parent node that has a `name` attribute of your choosing:

Also note that the function name is `simplexml_load_file` and not `simple_xml_loadfile`

```
foreach ($dom->xpath('item[@name="' . $selected . '"]/category') as $item)
{
   echo $item->attributes()->{'name'}. PHP_EOL;
}
```

Also note the usage of single vs. double quotes to enclose the attribute value.

For reference, this is the `xml` structure I used for testing:

```
<menu>
<item name="Pizzas">
    <category name="Onions"></category>
</item>
<item name="Salads">
    <category name = "Garden"></category>
    <category name = "Cesar"></category>
    <category name = "Onion and Tomato"></category>
</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Alex for the prompt and correct reply. Much appreciated!

Comment: Alex how would I go about making a variable an index of the session superglobal? For instance if I have a dynamic variable $x and I want to store it in my shopping cart $_SESSION array, can I access the session index with the syntax $_SESSION[$x] or would it be $_SESSION['.$x.']? Many thanks

Comment: I would say `$_SESSION[$x]` where `$x` would hold the value of the index. So, for example, if you would like to call `$_SESSION['items']` you can feel free and make a variable `$x="items"` and use it like I mentioned at the start.

Comment: One more question Alex, A table that is generated dynamically inside a form that uses post method and submits to calculator.php. The XML node that is being traversed contains 3 child elements. This means the table generated will have three rows,one apiece for all the three categories. How will I access this the post array for all the three nodes when i'm taken to calculator.php? Thanks

Comment: @chutzpah can you please submit this as a separate question? maybe adding some sample code and more details as I don't quite understand fully what you need.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Actually I did ask this as a separate question but it was down voted by many because of not being clear. And here is the edited version of the down voted question.<br> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936817/xml-shopping-cart-php-harvards-cs-s75-david-j-malan-pset0-pizzaml?noredirect=1#comment53699082_32936817